# Azure App services "Data out" exceeded the limit?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have Azure app services free plan. I am still in development stage. My Data out exceeded the limit.

What are the things that affect the Data out?

I see that for the free and shared plans the data out limit is 619.84 Mib

What is the data out limit for B1? I can't find that information in the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is no limit on the non-free plans, but once you exceed 165MB outbound you will incur standard data egress charges.

See [pricing details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/app-service/) for more info.